# Serving static content in Tomcat 10

Tags: jsp, tomcat, kml, tomcat10

I deployed a webapp on Tomcat 10 and at certain point it forms KML files to be displayed on map ([Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kml#layer)) and Google requires files to be publicaly available via URL. So in my app I decided to store formed files in specific temporary directory to serve them, then upload them to map and erase. How can I make a directory on my machine be available via URL in Tomcat 10?

I can access them if I packed them in war but that is not what I need. I tried adding

```
<Context docBase="/opt/tomcat/static" path="/kml/" />
```

element to server.xml but when I try to reach my file with `example.com\app-name\kml\file.txt` it throws me to 404. Other articles seem to be somewhat outdated. What would be the appropiate approach for Tomcat 10?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be I wasn't far off.

```
<Context docBase="${catalina.base}/static" path="AppName/kml/"/>
```

In server.xml under `<Host>` tag hosts static content from folder <CATALINA_BASE>/static on URL /AppName/kml.